# Perforce: Find source changelist for a branch

Tags: version-control, perforce, branching-and-merging

Short version:

After branching in P4, how can I find out the "source" changelist of the branch?

Long version:

Let's say I have a main branch of my project at

```
//project/main/...
```

The latest changelist submitted here is @123, when I decide to create a branch for release 1.0 in

```
//project/1.0/...
```

From P4V, a new changelist is created (say @130), resolved and submitted.

From the CLI, it would look something like this:

```
p4 integrate -c 123 -o //project/main/... //project/1.0/...
p4 submit
```

Later, I look at the changelists under `//project/1.0`, and see the @130 changelist containing a lot of branched files. 
How can I find out the changelist no. that this was originally branched ***from*** (that is, @123) ?

Comment: Nitpick: The CLI command is `p4 integrate //project/main/... //project/1.0/...`. (`-c 123` would fail because `-c` specifies a *pending* changelist. In your example 123 is an already *submitted* changelist.)

Comment: @Jon Do you work for Perforce? It so happens I contacted their support yesterday and they pointed out the same mistake I made :). The timing was perfect. By the way, the suggested I use `p4 filelog` with basically the same parameters you use for `p4 changes`, but I think your solution gives clearer results (i.e. I can just eyeball the changelist I need, as opposed to the "filelog" version which is a lot more verbose).

Comment: I know I gave a bad answer originally, but I totally revised it and went at it a totally different way.  I just wanted to notify you; I'm not sure if askers are notified of revised answers or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p4 changes` will display a list of submitted changelists, optionally filtered to a specific path.

```
p4 changes //project/main/...
Change 123 ... 'Very last change.'
Change 122 ... 'Next-to-last change.'
Change 100 ... 'Only two changes to go...'
...
```

No surprise there, but, as you've found, `p4 changes` is less helpful when you integrate all those changes in a single change:

```
p4 changes //project/1.0/...
Change 130 ... 'Integrated everything from main.'
```

**The trick is to use the `-i` option** which *includes any changelists integrated into the specified files*.

```
p4 changes -i //project/1.0/...
Change 130 ... 'Integrated everything from main.'
Change 123 ... 'Very last change.'
Change 122 ... 'Next-to-last change.'
Change 100 ... 'Only two changes to go...'
...
```

To get exactly what you want (`123`) you'll need to write a script which filters the output from `p4 changes -i //project/1.0/...` to remove any change listed by `p4 changes //project/1.0/...` (and then take the most recent remaining change).

(When exploring, I frequently also find the `-m max` option useful. This *limits changes to the 'max' most recent*. This helps your  output not flow offscreen when there are many changes.)

Comment: But am I guaranteed that the most recent change in `p4 changes -i` that's not in `p4 changes` will be the parent of a given changeset? I can merge changeset 123 into branch X, and then after that merge changeset 20. So how can I directly find the parent of a given changeset?

Comment: @AlexanderBird, no I don't think this solution works when merging in changes which occurred prior to the changes that have already been merged in.

Comment: Not very useful on large codebases. `Too many rows scanned (over 9000000); see 'p4 help maxscanrows'.
`

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the answers thus far provide the code for finding the source or root changelist of a branch, I thought I'd provide a one-liner to do just that.  This approach is based on @Cwan's suggestion, and will print the "parent" changelist from which the branch was created.  The `FIRST_BRANCH_CL` argument needs to be replaced with the branch creation changelist (i.e. the first changelist submitted to the new branch).  As a concrete example, replacing `FIRST_BRANCH_CL` with `130` from the original question, this one-liner would output `123`.

```sh
p4 describe -s FIRST_BRANCH_CL | perl -lne 'if(/^\.\.\. (.+#[0-9]+) .+$/) {print quotemeta $1}' | xargs p4 filelog -m1 | perl -lne 'if(/^\.\.\. \.\.\. branch from (.+#[0-9]+)/) {print quotemeta $1}' | xargs p4 fstat | perl -lne 'if(/^\.\.\. headChange (\d+)/) {$MaxCL=$1 if($1 > $MaxCL)} END {print $MaxCL}'
```

Comment: Hey, this actually seems to work! I've tried it on one of our branches, after first finding the same info using the manual steps outlined by Jon-Eric. It takes a while to run, though.

Comment: Nice one, but I think it would be great if you explained the rationale behind your one liner.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any simple command that performs what you would like to do. If you are willing to script a little bit and the command doesn't have to execute fast you could perhaps try to script something like the following for *all* branched files:

1. Find the source file/revision for a target file.

   > p4 filelog **//project/1.1/foo.bar#1**
   >   //project/1.1/foo.bar
   >   ... #1 change 6416 branch on 2009/07/10 by foo@bar (text) 'Release 1.1'
   >   ... ... branch from **//project/main/foo.bar**#1,**#2**
2. Get the change list at which the source file/revision was submitted.

   > p4 fstat **//project/main/foo.bar#2**
   >   ... depotFile //project/main/foo.bar
   >   ... headAction edit
   >   ... headType text
   >   ... headTime 1201771167
   >   ... headRev 2
   >   ... headChange **5353**
   >   ... headModTime 1201770971
3. Repeat for all files in branch and select the highest change no (headChange above), which should be the latest change submitted to the parent before branching for that specific file. You could get a complete listing of all branched files using e.g. "p4 files //project/1.0/...#1".

(or perhaps take the easy way out and ask Perforce support)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

Use the Revision Graph in P4V is step back through time and investigate the integration history. [Video on the Perforce website](http://filehost.perforce.com/downloads/media/rg/rg.html).

I have successfully used the revision graph on branches with thousands of files to track when an particular change was integrated into a branch. That is why I recommended it and linked to a training video as most people under-estimate it because they do not know how to use it.

**Long answer**:

... [Removed]

**UPDATE:** As the Revision Graph apparently is unfeasible, you can perhaps solve this using a process/policy, i.e., when you perform the integrate, add a note in the description "Branched @ CL 123". We used this approach ourselves when integrating from a trunk to release lines.

Comment: Having a couple hundred files in each branch makes the 'View revision graph' approach unfeasible, unfortunately. Since the command that creates the integration specifies the source changelist, I was hoping that information gets saved somewhere and I just don't know where to look. I guess there's always the fuzzy approach of checking timestamps of changelists in the source branch and finding the closest one to the timestamp of the integration.

Comment: Regarding the update to your answer: we *do* use something similar in our process; I just hoped there was an automatic way, and nobody cared to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**  I think this will work.  Try this:

```
p4 interchanges from_branch  to_branch
```

This will show unintegrated changes from your main branch to your release branch.  I believe you can use the top changelist number minus 1 to find your source changelist.  `interchanges` is an undocumented Perforce CLI feature.  To find out more, type `p4 help interchanges` to find out more about this command.

Again, I *think* this will work.  There may be some special cases where it will not, but it's my best guess to a tough and important problem.

Comment: Nitpicking a bit: If the branch was executed when change 120 was the last submitted change at //project/main, and the submitted integration change got numbered 129, then main@120 and 1.1@129 should be identical for most practical purposes, but remember that you can edit the target before submit by "promoting" the target to add using "p4 edit" and then modify the file's contents.

Comment: After the integration, I may need to cherry-pick changelists for back-porting from main to 1.0. I want the initial integration CL from /main (@123 in my example) in order to see exactly what was added to main after the integration point. (It's plausible that there may be changes in /main between @123 and @130)

Comment: I just got it. You are branching from a previous changelist, not (necessarily) the most recent one.

Comment: That's weird, I updated my question to admit my error and I got a -1.

Comment: -1 *Even* if you always integrate the most recent changelist from main, this approach *still* doesn't always work. Imagine a case where someone submits a change to `main` *after* you run `integrate` but *before* your `submit`. Making assumptions based on changelist numbers is almost always too sloppy.

Comment: @Jon-Eric, in principle you are correct.  My thought was that if someone submitted a changelist while you are integrating then you aren't really submitting the "most recent changelist", but your point still stands.  I was trying to make the best of a bad answer I originally gave since I misread the question.  But yes, I see your point, you can't assume two branches will be the same for a certain changelist number.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the history tab in p4v it will show you all changelists submitted against a branch, so look at this for

```
//project/1.0/...
```

once you have found the oldest submitted changelist, then on any one the files in that changelist view the Revision Graph for it, this will show you the branch that the file (and the rest of the files) were integrated from.

I'll see if I can come back with the p4 commands to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

"p4 integrated" worked for me. Look for "copy from" in the description